# How Create Relationship between those tables

Tags: c#

I Beginner programming
the question

There are two tables in the database
The first table by the names of students and degrees
Table II. There are the names of schools and grades required for each school

---

I want to link the two tables together so that each student show him his school as a science degree
The student the right to choose three schools and no more than that
And that the choices appear in the TextBox
Example:
Winning student's final grades (300) opens him all the schools
Winning student at (280) opens his school, which begins with this degree
And so on

Comment: I have upvoted your question as you are new and I don't want to turn you away. But you need to post more information, can you please post both of the tables structure? I.e - Columns and data types

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show code and an attempt, with explanation.

Comment: @AndrewKilburn You shouldn't upvote a question because someone is new, you should vote depending on the quality of the question. However your votes are yours to do with as you please.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder True, but you should give people a bit off lee-way when they're new. I believe this site to be far too critical at times

Comment: @AndrewKilburn However this site is not a writing service, the OP needs to show what they have tried and come back with a specific problem. Not this is what I want, do it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this an SQL question? You need to study designing a database, there is lots of help online, for example http://www.datanamic.com/support/lt-dez005-introduction-db-modeling.html.

You need many more than two tables. I would start with:

```
**Student**
StudentID
StudentName

**Degree**
DegreeID
DegreeName

**StudentResult**
ResultID
StudentID
DegreeID
Grade
```

This implements a many-to-many relationship between students and degrees - a student can have zero or more degrees and many students can take a given degree.

You will probably need to add other columns to these tables.

To answer your question, "How do I link the tables", `Student.StudentID` is a primary key and `StudentResult.StudentID` is a foreign key.

Something similar is necessary for your schools.

Please study the background and post any specific questions with your progress.